Example of a closed subscheme of $\operatorname{Proj} A$ which is not of the form $\operatorname{Proj}A/I$.
First, we know that in the case where $\operatorname{Proj} A$ is quasi-compact then no such example exists, so we need the irrelevant ideal to be finitely generated up to a radical.
Take $A=\mathbb C[x_0,x_1,\dots]$, then $A_+=\langle x_0,x_1,\dots,\rangle$ is a maximal ideal, and is thus radical, so $$A_+=\langle x_0,x_1,\dots,\rangle=\sqrt{\langle x_0,x_1,\dots,\rangle}$$
and it follows that $\operatorname{Proj}A$ is not quasicompact, so I think we should be able to find a closed subscheme $Z\subset \operatorname{Proj}A$ such that $Z$ is not projective, but I am struggling to see how to pick a homogenous ideal $I\subset A$ such that $V(I)$ is not projective.
Any help on constructing an example of this would be much appreciated.

Cross-posted with answer at MO.

$\newcommand{\Spec}{\operatorname{Spec}}\newcommand{\Proj}{\operatorname{Proj}}\newcommand{\P}{\mathbb P}\newcommand{\V}{\mathbb V}$
For posterity, I answer this question with the one answered over at MO, but in greater detail.
Take:
\begin{align*}
    \P^\infty_{k}=\Proj k[x_1,x_2,\dots]
\end{align*}
for any field $k$. Let:
\begin{align*}
    Z=\coprod_{i=1}^\infty X_i=\Spec k[x_1/x_i,x_2/x_i,\dots,\hat{x}_i/x_i,\dots]/\langle x_1/x_i,x_2/x_i,\dots,\hat{x}^i/x_i\rangle^i,\dots
\end{align*}
where the ideal:
\begin{align*}
    \langle x_1/x_i,x_2/x_i,\dots,\hat{x}^i/x_i,\dots\rangle^i
\end{align*}
is generated by all $i$th fold products of $\langle x_1/x_i,x_2/x_i,\dots,\hat{x}^i/x_i,\dots\rangle$. Note that
each scheme is is a singleton set as
\begin{align*}
    \sqrt{\langle x_1/x_i,x_2/x_i,\dots,\hat{x}^i/x_i,\dots\rangle^i}= \langle x_1/x_i,x_2/x_i,\dots,\hat{x}^i/x_i,\dots\rangle
\end{align*}
Denote each point by $0^i\in X_i\subset Z$ , and define a closed embedding by:
\begin{align*}
    f:Z&\longrightarrow \P^\infty_k\\
    0^i&\longmapsto [0,\dots,0, 1,0\dots,0,\dots]
\end{align*}
where the $1$ is in the $i$th position. If we take the homogenous ideal
$I=\langle x_ix_j:i\neq j\rangle$, then clearly for all $k$:
\begin{align*}
    (I_{x_k})_0=\langle x_1/x_k,x_2,x_k,\dots \hat{x}_k/x_k,\dots\rangle
\end{align*}
So under the identification $\V(I)\cap U_{x_i}=\V((I_{x_i}))\subset U_{x_i}=(\Spec k [x_1,\dots]_{x_i})_0$, we discern that
$\V(I)\cap U_{x_i}$ contains only the point $ [0,\dots,0, 1,0\dots,0,\dots]$, where the $1$
is again in the $i$th position. Clearly we then have that for all $U_{x_i}$, $f(Z)\cap U_{x_i}
=\V(I)\cap U_{x_i}$, hence $f(Z)=\V(I)$, and $f$ has closed image.
We set:
\begin{align*}
    I_i= \langle x_1/x_i,x_2/x_i,\dots,\hat{x}^i/x_i,\dots\rangle^i
\end{align*}
and define a sheaf morphism on the affine open cover $\{U_{x_i}\}_{i=1}^\infty$ via the canonical projections:
\begin{align*}
    f^\sharp_{U_{x_i}}:k[\{x_j/x_i\}_{j=1,j\neq i}^\infty]&\longrightarrow k[\{x_j/x_i\}_{j=1,j\neq i}^\infty]/I_i\\
    g&\longmapsto [g]
\end{align*}
and note that there is nothing to glue as $f^{-1}(U_{x_i}\cap U_{x+j})$ is the empty set. This sheaf homomorphism is clearly surjective on stalks so this defines a closed embedding $f$.
We claim that there is no homogenous ideal $I$ such that $Z\cong \Proj A/I$. Indeed, suppose
there was. Then we would have that for all $x_i$,
\begin{align*}
    (I_{x_i})_0=I_i
\end{align*}
Indeed, suppose $f\in I$ is homogenous of degree $d$, then $f/1\in I_{x_i}$, and
$f/x_i^d\in (I_{x_i})_0$. For the above to be true, we must then
have that $f/x_i^d\in I_i$ for all $i$ as well. However,
if $k>d$, then $f/x_k^d$ cannot lie in $I_k$ as every element must a be a sum of at least $k$-fold product
of elements of the form $x_j/x_k$, while $f/x_k^d$ can only be a sum of $d$-fold products  of said elements.
It follows that for some $k$ we must have that:
\begin{align*}
    (I_{x_k})_0\not\subset I_k
\end{align*}
implying that $Z\not\cong \Proj A/I$ for any homogenous ideal $I$.

and you accepted ‘your own’ answer (which isn’t your own) but not the one provided on MO. That’s very unfair to the original answer.

Oh I meant to do that on MO ages ago. that wasn’t supposed to happen. I just wanted to explain the example in my own words, on here since no one had put an answer here. If the og author wants to put the same answer here they are more than welcome to and I’ll accept that one.
